# A group of type F that is an extension of type F-by-type F

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, group-cohomology, classifying-spaces

Let us first recall that a group of type $F$ is a group admitting a compact classifying space.

Let $K$ and $Q$ be groups of type $F$. Consider the family $\mathcal{G}(K, Q)$ consisting of groups $G$ of type $F$ for which there exists a short exact sequence
$$
1 \to K \to G \to Q \to 1. 
$$

Is it true that all groups in $\mathcal{G}(K, Q)$ have the same cohomological dimension?

If not, please give me a counterexample.

Comment: what if after applying the classifying space functor $B$ the associated Serre spectral sequence collapses? Doesn't this imply that cohomological dimension of $G$ is the sum of other two?

Answer (score 6):

Here is a partial answer. Theorem 5.5 of Homological Dimension of Discrete Groups by Bieri implies that the cohomological dimension of $G$ is the sum of the cohomological dimensions of $K$ and $Q$ provided $H^n(K,ZK)$ is free abelian where n is the cohomological dimension of $K$. He also only needs $K$ and $Q$ of type FP.